# Adding a point shapefile to a raster image with no spatial information

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system, point

I have a raster image (JPG) of a fictional map from a fantasy book.

I want to add a point shapefile in order to show main events from the book upon the map.

My map has no spatial information (as it is fictional) and therefore I am unable to "start editing" the image, which prevents me from adding points.

Any advice to how I can add a points to a JPG image with no spatial information?

This is the map I'm trying to add a point shapefile to.

http://www.ursulakleguin.com/EarthseaMaps/

Comment: I know this isnt a GIS answer, but why not use Illustrator/Inkscape or Photoshop/Gimp and just add points where you wish.  If this is a fantasy map that has no coordinates there isnt really a need to use a GIS software package.

Comment: Because I want there to be a point-file which holds additional information, such as text describing the event and location. I wish to make an interactive map, rather than a static image.

Comment: Add point using draw toolbar, export it to shapefile, might work

Comment: I managed to add a point and export it as a point-shape file. However, the attributes table does not have the X&Y coordinates of the point. Is it possible to add the X&Y coordinates of the point to the attribute table?

Comment: Add XY Coordinates tool will populate two fields in the attribute table with the coordinates. If you later move the feature (geometry), the values in these fields will not be updated. It's a static version of the feature's coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new point shapefile without a coordinate system with the attributes you are interested in (Location and events). I called it Story_Points. You can then edit the Story_Points to create point features on top of your JPG image.

[image: Arcmap Layers for adding information to JPG]

Comment: When I click start edit, I receive an error.

Arcmap states there are no editable layers. 

The only layer I have is a JPG raster image of my fantasy map.

Comment: You can't edit the JPG, you will need to create a new point shapefile and edit that.

Comment: Here is the map i'm trying to add a point-shape file to. 

http://www.ursulakleguin.com/EarthseaMaps/

The error is that there is no editable layers.

Comment: You need to create/add an editable layer to the mxd. I edited my answer to include a screen shot of my mxd.

Comment: How did you create/add an editable layer to the mxd?

Comment: See esri help on creating a new shapefile: http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//005600000004000000